# Hiding Label in Tab in React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a problem hiding the label in my react native tab. I'm using `react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs.`

Pls see my code below

```
 <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Requests"
        backBehavior="initialRoute"
        shifting={true}
        activeColor={theme.colors.primary}
        inactiveColor={color(theme.colors.text).alpha(0.6).rgb().string()}
        sceneAnimationEnabled={false}
        showLabel={false}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Requests"
          component={Requests}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: "comment-question-outline",
            tabBarColor,
          }}
        />
        ...
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its labeled={false} not showLabel={false}

```
 <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Requests"
        backBehavior="initialRoute"
        shifting={true}
        activeColor={theme.colors.primary}
        inactiveColor={color(theme.colors.text).alpha(0.6).rgb().string()}
        sceneAnimationEnabled={false}
        labeled={false}
      >
```